# Using regular expression match with string only for certain condition

Tags: regex, python-2.7

1 Abc dent meant bill and enjoy mill

2 Abc dent meant ( abc dent meant bill and enjoy mill )

I want to using regular rexpression fetch the word after 'meant'
Only when it between 'meant' and 'and'.

So answer in above case should be

Bill

Bill

How can I do that using regular expression in Python 
I search for it on stackoverflow but couldn't find answer

Comment: What have you tried? Welcome to SO.  See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

## Description

Python allows the use of lookarounds which can validate the desired substring exists without actually capturing it.

```regex
(?<=\bmeant\s)\w+(?=\sand\b)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- find the single word between `meant` and `and`
- require `meant` and `and` to be stand alone words, and not embedded into other words.

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/eE8hF2/3

**Sample text**

note the edge case in line 3 where the word `android` starts with the word `and` so the match is avoided.

```
1 Abc dent meant bill and enjoy mill

2 Abc dent meant ( abc dent meant droids and enjoy mill )

3 Arthur Dent meant tractors android when he said droid.
```

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [17-21] `bill`

MATCH 2
1.  [72-78] `droids`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    meant                    'meant'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    and                      'and'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

`meant\s+([a-z]+)\s+and`

[a-z]+ matches all characters between a and z multiple times

\s+ matches multiple spaces

the parentheses around [a-z]+ puts the match into a capturing group so that you can use it later

Here it is in action: https://regex101.com/r/hW5fP7/3

here is a nice site to learn more about regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Can you please explain me this

Comment: Can u explain me this syntax please

Comment: what if I also want compare special character along with a-z in regex pls reply

Comment: @Girl4rmsydney, add it inside your square brackets. And don't forget to escape them when necessary. eg:`[a-z!&]` will match a-z, ! and &.